# Autowired problem with a bean

Tags: java, spring, annotations, dwr

with spring 2.5,

i have a class StockDwr

StockDwr it's a bean name stock who have a prototype scope

in this class, i have an attribute ModRepository with @Autowired annotation

ModRepository is usedd only by this class

in this class i only have that (because i try to find the problem)

```
public void read(String fileName) {
    System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

when i go to the jsp who use stock i get

Error creating bean with name 'stock': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.domain.ModRepository com.web.StockDwr.modRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.domain.ModRepository] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [com.domain.ModRepository]: expected at least 1 matching bean

i don't defined  ModRepository in xml file, i tried to do it, but it get the same problem

any idea?

Comment: How did you try to define ModRepository exactly?

Comment: <bean id="modRepository" class="com.domain.ModRepository"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have made incorrect bean definition for ModRepository in the xml file. spring is not able to find the bean com.domain.ModRepository

Autowiring happens byType. Is your ModRepository implementation of some interface? In that case if there are many implementation spring will not be able to identify a bean uniquely.

To avoid that use @Qualifier annotation. Qualifier makes sure the autowiring happens byName.

Alternatively you can try with the annotation, Put a @Component on top of ModRepository class
and make sure you have these two lines in your applicationContext.xml

```
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.domain" />
```

Comment: with @Component that work, but i don't understand why i need to put this annonation. i tried to add other bean (who don't have @Component) and that work... so don't really now the problem with ModRepository

Comment: may be you need a @qualifier annotation to make autowiring byName instead of byType

Comment: i try with and without Interface for ModRepository, same thing... i tried Qualifier annotation on the ModRepository attribute in my StockDwr but i get the same error if i don't put Component annotation...

Comment: when you put Qualifier annotation, did you also define the qualifier in the xml mapping?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because spring has no knowledge of your ModRepository object. To autowire something, spring has to know about what that something is. You say you tried to define ModRepository in your application context xml, but still getting the same error. In that case, you must have defined it incorrectly because that is exactly what you have to do.

Comment: habitualty if you put Autowired, you don't need to define it in the xml file.  i added in the xml file:<bean id="modRepository" class="com.domain.ModRepository"/>

Comment: "habitualty if you put Autowired, you don't need to define it in the xml file" - this is not entirely correct. You ALWAYS have to define the ModRepository bean itself, either in the XML like you indicated, or by annotating your ModRepository implementation with (at)Service, (at)Component or the likes.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you configured

```
   <context:component-scan base-package="..."/>.
```

Without @Component annotation, Spring has no way to know which class is a component that it should keep track of.

Answer (score -1):

@Autowired using annotations

@Repository("ExampleDao") public class ExampleDaoImpl implements ExampleDao

@Service("ServiceExample") public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService

@Controller public class ExampleController

@Autowired private ExmpleService ServiceExample;